# How to reset min/max values for jQuery scrollspy on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, position, scrollspy

I am using this [scrollspy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy) plugin and I need **to reset min/max values when window is resized**, because the first section resizes in height and affects all `position.top` of following sections. What would be the best way to do this?

```
$('section').each(function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    $(this).scrollspy({
        min: position.top - $header.outerHeight(),
        max: position.top + $(this).outerHeight() - $header.outerHeight(),
        onEnter: function(element) {
            $('#main-menu').find('a[href$="'+$(element).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('cur');
            /* window.location.hash = 'panel-'+$(element).attr('id'); */
        },
        onLeave: function(element) {
            $('#main-menu').find('a[href$="'+$(element).attr('id')+'"]').removeClass('cur');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try setting the positions of your section relative

Comment: yes! works - thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the position of the section elements to relative.

```
position:relative;
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I couldn't change my elements to be positon relative since they are all custom animations and needed to be in position absolute.

This was my approach.

```
// Make sure to update Scrollspy once the last resize has fired
var rtime = new Date(1, 1, 2000, 12,00,00);
var timeout = false;
var delta = 200;
$(window).resize(function() {
    rtime = new Date();
    if (timeout === false) {
        timeout = true;
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    }
});

function resizeend() {
    if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    } else {
        timeout = false;
        $(window).unbind("scroll");
        // Your Scrollspy function
    }               
}
```